# Name confliction in chat rooms

Tags: bug, chat, display-names

I enters in a chat room every day . But last Saturday I did not come here . But a user having the same name  as mine user name was in the room . some people was chatting with that user . But as I was not in the room , I should not get the notifications for chat messages for that room. Today I received a mail from stack-overflow as notifications for those chat messages . I checked it out but that was not for me . These were for the user having same user name . Is it bug??

Comment: It's by design, Stack Exchange allows duplicate display names.

Comment: @ShadowWizard ok. But I got a  mail for chat notification messages which were intended for that person.

Comment: Right, but same will happen with comments.